# Would MetaMask snaps support BIP39-keys? What's the feasibility of adding support for Kadena that uses BIP44?

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, metamask, kadena

I'm looking into creating a MetaMask snap that interacts with RPCs for Kadena (Chainweaver). It seems that Chainweaver uses BIP44 as the key generation standard. How feasible is it to integrate BIP39 keys onto a MetaMask snap that uses BIP44 as a standard?

Answer (score 0):

Developer documentation for the MetaMask Ethereum wallet
https://docs.metamask.io/guide/snaps-rpc-api.html#restricted-methods

There is an RPC method to get BIP 44 keys